# Global calendar of Open Source-related events

Tags: data-request, software, calendar, open-source

I am looking for a calendar of events related to Open Source:

- Linux User Groups regular meetings
- Web seminar about particular Open Source technologies
- Tech conferences related to Open Source
- Hackathons
- etc

Is there such a calendar?
Answers for particular countries are OK too.

Answer (score 5):

- [Hackathon Watch](http://www.hackathonwatch.com/) - not specific to open source or open data though
- [European PSI / Open Data Events](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=d8ctpd90brkif2u7emhrv03kqc@group.calendar.google.com) - European, not global
- Lanyard's [Open Data](http://lanyrd.com/topics/open-data/) and [Open Source](http://lanyrd.com/topics/open-source/) lists (can be saved to your calendar, see the right column)
- ...

(please edit if you want to add a calendar)

Answer (score 2):

This calendar is maintained by RedHat:

http://opensource.com/resources/conferences-and-events-monthly

Unfortunately it contains very few events, and does not seem to have an API.

[image: OpenSource.com calendar]

Answer (score 1):

This Google Calendar contains most Open Source-related events in Japan:

https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=fvijvohm91uifvd9hratehf65k@group.calendar.google.com

Most events (but not all) are about Open Source topics.

[image]